# Should pure CoffeeScript questions tag JavaScript?

Tags: discussion, tags

This question is related to [Coffeescript tag in javascript library questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105472/coffeescript-tag-in-javascript-library-questions), but I do not think it is a duplicate.

If a question is asking about CoffeeScript (which compiles into JavaScript) but does not really have anything to do with JavaScript, should it still be tagged with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)?

[Inheritance in CoffesScript doesn't correctly work because of lodash merge function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163073/inheritance-in-coffesscript-not-working-correct) is the question that prompted me asking this.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76058/retag-questions-in-the-django-tag-with-python-as-well

Comment: @sth good find. sounds like the decision there was that the output language (JavaScript/Python) tag **should be removed from the question.** This probably suffices as an answer if you'd like to repost as such...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CoffeeScript, and JavaScript are two different languages with different syntax. Tagging a question about CoffeeScript with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) doesn't make sense, as the users who don't know CoffeeScript cannot answer a question about CoffeeScript.

If the question is about the JavaScript code generated from CoffeeScript code, then I would probably use [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript); in the other cases, I would use [coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coffeescript).

Comment: I think this is the concensus. Strong relation between the two languages does not imply both tags.

Comment: Whenever I see a CS question pop up, I immediately remove the JS tag and get the heck away from it.